# How to use multiple button for same function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript. I want to create multiple button with same function and result will be shown in same place. From my code I want to change tip1 value for every button click event. How can I do this? Please help me if any one have any idea.

My codes are below:

```
<form id="calculator">
    <p>Amount: <input id="amount" /></p>
    <p>Years: <input id="year" /></p>
    <hr />
    <p>Tip: <input id="tip" disabled="disabled" /></p>
    <p>Total: <input id="total" disabled="disabled" /></p>
    <button onclick="calculate()" id="1">Button1</button>
    <button onclick="calculate1()" id="2">Button2</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function calculate () {     
  var amount = $('#amount').val();
  var year = $('#year').val(); 
  if (button 1) {
    var tip1 = (1 + 115 / 100);  
  } 
  else if (button 2) {
    var tip1 = (1 + 215 / 100);
  }    

  var tip = Math.pow(tip1, year);
  var total = amount * tip;
  $('#tip').val( tip.toFixed(2) );
  $('#total').val( total.toFixed(2) );
  return false;
  }

  $('#calculator').submit( calculate );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
function calculateF(target) {
    var amount = parseFloat($('#amount').val());
    var year = parseFloat($('#year').val());

    if (target == 1) {
        var tip1 = (1 + 115 / 100);
    } else if (target == 2) {
        var tip1 = (1 + 215 / 100);
    }
    
    var tip = Math.pow(tip1, year);
    var total = amount * tip;
    $('#tip').val(tip.toFixed(2));
    $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
    return false;
}

$('button').click(function(e) {
    calculateF($(e.target).prop('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p>Amount: <input id="amount" /></p>
    <p>Years: <input id="year" /></p>
    <hr />
    <p>Tip: <input id="tip" disabled="disabled" /></p>
    <p>Total: <input id="total" disabled="disabled" /></p>
    <button id="1">Button1</button>
    <button id="2">Button2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, by passing ID directly

```js
function calculate (id) {     
   var amount = $('#amount').val();
   var year = $('#year').val(); 
   var tip1 = 0;
   if (id == "1") {
  tip1 = (1 + 115 / 100);  
   } 
   else if (id == "2") {
  tip1 = (1 + 215 / 100);
   }    
 
   var tip = Math.pow(tip1, year);
   var total = amount * tip;
   $('#tip').val( tip.toFixed(2) );
   $('#total').val( total.toFixed(2) );
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Amount: <input id="amount" /></p>
<p>Years: <input id="year" /></p>
<hr />
<p>Tip: <input id="tip" disabled="disabled" /></p>
<p>Total: <input id="total" disabled="disabled" /></p>
<button onclick="calculate(this.id)" id="1">Button1</button>
<button onclick="calculate(this.id)" id="2">Button2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `var tip1` at wrong places.

Just Use this to call the function `calculate(id)`.

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    calculate(this.id);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="calculator">
    <p>Amount: <input id="amount" /></p>
    <p>Years: <input id="year" /></p>
    <hr />
    <p>Tip: <input id="tip" disabled="disabled" /></p>
    <p>Total: <input id="total" disabled="disabled" /></p>
    <button id="1">Button1</button>
    <button id="2">Button2</button>
</form>
```

`calculate()` function

```
function calculate () {     
  var amount = $('#amount').val();
  var year = $('#year').val(); 
  var tip1;
  if (id=="1") {
    tip1 = (1 + 115 / 100);  
  } 
  else if (id=="2") {
    tip1 = (1 + 215 / 100);
  }    

  var tip = Math.pow(tip1, year);
  var total = amount * tip;
  $('#tip').val( tip.toFixed(2) );
  $('#total').val( total.toFixed(2) );
  return false;
  }
```